# Missing Packages for Equation Preview in Sublime

Tags: latextools

I have been attempting to set up LaTeX editing in Sublime through use of SublimeText and LaTeX Tools.

I have installed many of the required programs to go along with it, but I've had trouble with "packages for equation preview". They are listed as missing and I cannot figure out how to install them.

Part of my issue is I cannot figure out exactly what packages I need to install as the name given for them (standalone, preview, etc.) is rather vague.

[image: My LaTeXTools System Check]

How would I go about installing these packages?

Comment: The names you read are the names of the packages in MiKTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and thank you very much for your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch MiKTeX Console (as Administrator), select `Packages`. In the list of packages, select those  you want to install, rightclick on anyt of them and select `Install Packages`, like in this screenshot:[image]

Comment: That works! Thanks so much

Comment: I thought it was the TeXLive screen, so I didn't answer :-). My compliments.

Comment: Sublime Text console mentioned MiKTeX, @Sebastiano. I first posted a comment to ask for the distribution, then deleted it after I read some details of the console.

Comment: @Bernard You know so many things I don't know about :-)